# Call by Value/Value-Result

Tags: parameter-passing

I am given the following code and asked what it will print out depending on how it is called:

```
int a;
procedure foo(int x){
x = x + 10;
a = a + x;
}
procedure fie( ){
a = 5;
foo(a);
print (a);
```

It asks for `call by value` and `call by value-result`

For call by value I know that it would get 20 because you end up adding 10 to x which carries the value 5, then adding 15 to the original a which becomes 20.

My problem is why does the `call by value-result` print 15? Can someone give me a good explanation, I am confused on how exactly `value-result` and `value` differ from each other and how `value-result` is actually interpreted.

Comment: The code you have presented is not C.

Comment: Just to add to what @SteveSummit said... there is no `procedure` keyword in C.

Comment: my mistake, just a mis-tag @SteveSummit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given example is only about 'call by value' and that is why the printed value is 20.
In case of 'call by value-result' actual parameter supplied by the caller is copied into the callee's formal parameter;
Then when the function is run the formal parameter could be modified anywhere inside the function body but only when function exits the modified formal parameter is then copied back to the caller. 
In case of 'call by reference' an 'alias' is created between the formal and actual parameters and any modification to formal parameter is reflected to the caller parameter.

Having the code in a language that support 'call by value-result'

```
void test(IN OUT int c; REF int d)
{
     printf ("a: %d b: %d c: %d d: %d\n", a,b,c,d);
     a = 0; b = 9; c = 4; d = 6; 
     printf ("a: %d b: %d c: %d d: %d\n", a,b,c,d);
}
void main(void) 
{
      int a = 5, b = 7;
      test(a,b);
      printf ("a: %d b: %d\n",a,b);
}
```

The results of this should be

```
 a: 5 b: 7 c: 5 d: 7
 a: 0 b: 6 c: 4 d: 6  // d and b are aliases, so b=9 is modified by d = 6 
 a: 4 b: 6            // a replaced with value of c on function exit.
```

So in your case :
call by value

a = 5 when you enter the function

```
x = 5 + 10 = 15
```

then we have 'a' as global variable

```
a = 5 + x = 5 + 15 = 20
```

then on print a = 20

in case of call by value- result
when entering the function

```
x = 5 + 10 = 15
a = 5 + 15 = 20
```

but when the function is return the value if x is copied on 'a' which result a = 15
then the print is 15

Comment: @lucci the `call by value` answer is 20, you stated that it is 15. I understand the `call by value` I just don't get why `call by value-result` is 15.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. You are right in case of call by value the printed result is 20 and call by value result is 15.

Comment: can you explain the `call by value result` process, I am lost on why it is 15. does it have something to do with a being a global variable or something? It still doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I think I actually have it now, please correct me if I don't. Since the actual parameter is copied into the callee's formal parameter, when you make `x` 15, you copying the `x` back into a at the end of `foo`?

Comment: Yes, you got it.I have updated the answer. Hope that it is OK now

Comment: @luci The result (15) is incorrect, or my code below is (incorrect).  If I'm incorrect in how I coded it in C++, please leave feedback.

Comment: @Jfevold, The example I gave is not in C or C++, it is more like ADA or other languages that support such feature.It only exemplify the "call-by-value" and "call-by-value-result" differences. So your code could be correct and provide the responses that you get but it is not apply in this case.

Comment: @luci to be extra clear, I believe you are absolutely incorrect in your statement that the result is 15. My c++ code is my supporting argument. If you don't believe that's a valid suporting argument, please tell me why.

Comment: @luci You are right.  15 is right.  I found my coding error, and corrected below.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: My previous answer was wrong.  It has now been corrected.

C/C++ do not implement anything like Call-By-Value-Result (natively).  As I understand it, that's an ADA term (Working on government code?).  Call-By-Value would result in 15, Call-By-Reference is the trickiest one, because you would be modifying `a` in line 3 as well as line 4 of your example.

--EDIT--

I have implemented the following code, which I believe to be a valid representation of the syntax described (I'm not familiar enough with ADA to do the test directly, maybe someone else can).  As you will see, the result for By-Value-Result is 15.

```
#include <iostream>


int a_v, a_r, a_vr;

void foo_by_val(int x)
{
  x = x + 10;
  a_v = a_v + x;
}

void foo_by_ref(int &x)
{
  x = x + 10;
  a_r = a_r + x;
}

void foo_by_value_result(int &x_ref)
{
  int x = x_ref;
  x = x + 10;
  a_vr = a_vr + x;
  //  x = x_ref;  <-- My previous mistake
  x_ref = x;
}


void fie( ){
  a_v = 5;
  a_r = 5;
  a_vr = 5;


  foo_by_val(a_v);
  foo_by_ref(a_r);
  foo_by_value_result(a_vr);


  std::cout << "By Value: " << a_v << std::endl;
  std::cout << "By Refference: " << a_r << std::endl;
  std::cout << "By Value Result: " << a_vr << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
  fie();
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
By Value: 20
By Reference: 30
By Value Result: 15
```